# Creating a forms application with hardware acceleration

Tags: java, wpf, swing, awt, hardware-acceleration

Do any of javax.awt, javax.swing or windows forms components support hardware acceleration?
Is WPF the only way to use hardware acceleration on a forms application, what would be the best alternative for WPF?

Comment: It depends on what you consider 'hardware acceleration'. In general you wouldn't be concerned about 'getting' hardware accelerated but instead you would want the application to be fast.

Comment: @Erno I want graphics card to do the drawing of components on the screen, because when I have many elements on the screen resizing becomes troublesome.

Comment: @ugurcode How many elements do you have? I have made forms with over 2000 components without being it a problem. Are you sure there is not something else lying there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a modern framework so as to enjoy hardware acceleration. WPF/Silverlight is the solution from Microsoft, but they are for .NET only. You can check other vendors' solutions, such as Embarcadero's FireMonkey.

AWT, Swing, WinForms are too old to support that. But due to the rise of HTML 5, web applications get hardware acceleration easier and earlier than most desktop apps, because web browsers such as Internet Explorer/Firefox/Google Chrome already support it.